# Streaming MP4 frames to HTML5, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, html, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mp4

Currently I am generating a MP4 Bitstream using Intel's Media SDK library, which uses ffmpeg underneath the covers.  I can generate a mp4 file, and play it and it works.

However, when I try to stream that mp4 across the network, it doesn't play within the HTML5 video player, as tested within Chrome, Firefox, or IE.

This much is sent back and forth across the network:

```
Sent by Chrome:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8085
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Range: bytes=0-

From my video player:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Thu, 09 Jan 2014 17:28:14 GMT
Content-type: video/mp4
```

After this, I send a newline, and all the video frames, one after another, while listening to see if I receive anything back from the browser.

Then nothing happens.  Any suggestions to get this playing video?  Thank you!

Comment: Are you streaming an existing stream or streaming from a file? If its a live stream then I have the same struggle - a MP4 continuous stream generated from ffmpeg (from IP camera stream) and have found that I can't attach to the running mp4 http stream with HTML5 clients. This is because although the HTTP headers are correct (I use Node.js and the code works fine for streaming files) the client isn't cleanly connecting to the stream and doesn't receive the correct MP4 header and container bytes.

Comment: cont.. You also need to adjust the moov atom so that the moov atom is empty and the keyframes setup as fragmented (ffmpeg movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov). If you are streaming a file it is easier but you need to move the moov atom to the start of the file so that seeking works.

Comment: Good to know, thank you.. anyone know if there is a way to enable something like frag_keyframe from the API instead of the command line?

Comment: I see you are streaming from a file, if so the ffmpeg command line options are different to live streaming (I use ffmpeg segmentation to split the file into smaller files which allows streaming the recording before the recording is finished).

Comment: Here is a GIST from my working application that shows the ffmpeg command line, node.js HTTP streaming server (you will need an equivalent in C#) and HTML5 client. 
[link](https://gist.github.com/deandob/8943268)

Answer (score -1):

After many days on trying to stream HTML5 video to an iPad, I recognized the problem of WCF returning zero as the length for returning range bytes (`0-xxxxxx`, `xxxxxx-yyyyyyy`, `0-` etc.).

I eventually got around this by using IKVM from within C# and use Java sockets to stream the data. This also gives you the opportunity to use the PC/server IP address without a port number (e.g. `192.1.1.3/myvideo.html`) as required by WCF.